# Creating New Dataframe Based on Values in Different Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to create append a dataframe based on the value in the previous column of the dataframe and values from another dataframe.

The problem that I am working on asks me to generate a random number from 0 to 1 for 50 individuals over 100 time periods. Each individual starts in the location x=0 and have the possibility of moving back and forth between x=0 and x=1. If the number they generated that period is greater than 0.9, they switch locations (so if they were in x=0 in the previous period, they will move to x=1; if they were in x=1 in the previous period, they will move to x=0). If the number is not greater than 0.9, they stay in the same location as the previous time period. I am trying to find each individual's location for each time period.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#First I generated a 50x100 dataframe of random numbers
rv = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low = 0.0, high = 1.0, size=(51, 100)), columns = range(1,101))
#print(rv)

#Next, I created a new dataframe that tells me whether the value in the random number dataframe is greater than 0.9
rv_2 = rv[rv > 0.9].notnull()
#rv_2

#this is where I am stuck right now
#First I made a dataframe where every individual starts at location x=0 
rv_3 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = range(51), columns = range(1))

#Here I am trying to append the location of each individual for each time period
#I was trying to add a 1 in the rv_3 dataframe if the previous column had a 0 and the corresponding value in the rv_2 dataframe was true, and so on
for col in rv_2:
    for i, row_value in rv_2[col].iteritems():
        if rv_2[col][i] == True & rv_3[col][i-1] == 0:
            rv_3[col][i] = 1
        elif rv_2[col][i] == True & rv_3[col][i-1] == 1:
            rv_3[col][i] = 1
        else:
            rv_3[col][i] = rv_3[col][i-1]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: does this work for you ?
rv_2.cumsum(axis='columns')[100]%2

Comment: I don't think so. I need to be able to graph where each individual is for each time period, not just the ending time periods.

Comment: I selected the last step, if you need at every individual step you can use ```rv_2.cumsum(axis='columns')%2```